# Unable to generate metamodel definitions using DataNucleus JPACriteriaProcessor from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jpa, annotations, jpa-2.0, datanucleus

I'm trying to generate the metamodel definitions in Eclipse as documented on:
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jpa/jpql_criteria.html

My project compiler level is set to 1.6 and the mentioned datanucleus jars are added to the factory path.
When the project builds I get the following error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'X'.
Could not initialize class org.datanucleus.jpa.query.JPACriteriaProcessor
```

When using mvn compile the metamodel definitions are generated successfully, so it's probably related to Eclipse annnotation processing.

I'm using latest Spring Tool Suite 3.1.0.RELEASE based on Eclipse 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Not put persistence-api.jar (or equivalent, such as Geronimo specs JPA2) in the Factory Path? Either way one of the deps is missing